# sync grayed out in sharepoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

in one of our document library the sync is disabled when we tried to configure sync to a folder. 
the sync is working on other document libraries.
The "Allow items from this site to be downloaded to offline clients?" is set to yes . but still it is disabled.

Comment: is it a picture library ?

Comment: check Library settings -> Advanced Settings -> Offline Client Availability. If it is set to No, we can't sync it. What is the value in that setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that Offline Client availability is set to yes in that doc lib as below. If its set to No, click on Yes and then OK

Library settings -> Advanced Settings -> Offline Client Availability

[image]

In the "New/Modern" experience, you can select it as below:

[image]

Also, if its a `picture library` then it will be `disabled` as its supported.

Reference - [Sync button grayed out](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sync-button-greyed-out-in-sharepoint/86a62b89-9e7b-4610-9806-a0d778f328ac)

Comment: Thanks. I found this setting deep within the library settings. BUt now my local copy is Read Only for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Sync settings can be enabled/disabled by Offline Client Availability of library.

go to Advance Settings, find Offline Client Availability and Set option
"Allow items from this document library to be downloaded to offline clients?" to Yes. this will enable sync settings.